# Change Packet Reception Ratio using simulation script in Cooja, Contiki OS

Tags: directed-graph, contiki

I am currently running simulation in Cooja to simulate a WSN using the Directed Graph Radio Model.

Due to the research requirement, I will need to change the Packet Reception Ratio in the DGRM Configurator between nodes dynamically using scripts. May I ask how to change the PRR between nodes in Cooja simulation scipts?

Comment: What I think might worthy of mentioning is, if you are not able to compile the RealSim plugin using ant command and import it to cooja, the following suggestions might help: 1. Change the path of cooja in build.xml
2. Change the import lines in the java to correct path, for example, for contiki 2.7, the path of import package from org.contikios.cooja to se.sics.cooja
3. Change ‘Cooja’ to ‘GUI’ in the import lines and the declearations
4. Change the path in cooja.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulations scripts expose only a very limited subset of Cooja's interface, so it's not possible as far as I know.

Use [RealSim](https://github.com/cmorty/realsim/tree/master/cooja-plugin) instead. It allows to dynamically change link quality in a specific time by describing these changes in a trace file.

Alternatively, you can try to extend the interface exported to simulation scripts. Look at the file `tools/cooja/java/org/contikios/cooja/plugins/LogScriptEngine.java` in Contiki sources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! I have installed RealSim plugin and it works good! Many Thanks!